# Which of SQL Server Express, IBM DB2 Express, Oracle XE should be used?

Tags: c#, database

I'm looking for a free high-quality database server for a C# application to be deployed in small business environments where the number of workstations will be between 2 and 20.  In many cases there will be no dedicated server which means that the database server will need to be installed on one of the workstations.

Which of the above free database servers would be most suitable for my needs?

I am leaning towards SQL Server Express because it probably has more support and free updates etc and is probably better suited to programming in C#.

Comment: It depends, mostly on your experience and skill working with the server. Not a constructive question.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee: are you suggesting there is a significant learning curve to work with other DB servers?  I doubt it.  We're not talking about rocket science here.

Comment: There is quite a difference in learning curve between SQL Server and Oracle, Sql is much easier, it just works. Oracle really involves you in all kinds of technical details that in 99% of cases just don't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For databases to be deployed to small businesses and with 2-20 users, I would go with SQL any time.

I've worked extensively with both, SQL server will get the job done in a fraction of the effort, it just works. Cleint tools are so much better compared to Oracle's.

Oracle will force you to tweak all kinds of technical knobs and dials to work, things I never had to touch or even think about with SQL server. If you don't set them, Oracle will not work well. If you set them wrong, Oracle defenitely not work well. Right now I'm forced to work with Oracle at my work and I've actually just installed SQL 2012 RC0 on my own workstation just so I can run some basic queries in a reasonble amount of time. A team of DBA's are unable to get the wretched thing to perform. I'll stop here, I'm getting all worked up again.

Also small businesses are likely to have windows domains, so you can use Integrated Security (out of the box).

Complete no-brainer, go with SQL Server Express. I envy you.

Gert-Jan

Answer (score 3):

I would go for **SQL Server Express**, mainly because it is a Microsoft solution and will work well with other Microsoft products.

I've not got a lot of experience with Oracle solutions, but to my knowledge the only time you'd choose to use Oracle is when you specifically need to use the functionality provided with Oracle.

If you're dipping your toes in you could always go with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you use Microsoft technologies like .NET, other Microsoft technologies like MS SQL Server are of course those with the best integration.

> In many cases there will be no dedicated server which means that the
>   database server will need to be installed on one of the workstations.

Why you don't use a file based SQL "server", like [**SQLite**](http://www.sqlite.org/)? Or a few XML files together with [**LINQ to XML**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)? These alternatives were both very powerfull and do not require additional licenses.

**EDIT:**
Problem with wifi you mentioned should never occur because the database file is stored on the local machine. If you accessed a single database file over network from multiple clients, you should definitely use a real SQL server.

Comment: I have experienced bad results with file based databases such as JET, particularly over wifi networks which seem to be the rage these days in small businesses.

Comment: Also, why do you mention licences when all the alternatives I suggested in the question are free?

Comment: @CraigJohnston: IMHO these alternatives are better than using a massive package like MS SQL Server and install it on every client (I personally don't like it when my new VAIO notebook ships with SQL Server Express preinstalled when its only used for one the useless media tools bundled). And these alternatives are free of charge, so you don't have additional costs if you use one of these instead of the alternatives you mentioned. Why do you mention wifi? File base databases are stored on the local machine!

Comment: I am talking about a database which is accessed by multiple workstations.  I agree that a file based DB would be suitable for single workstation use, but in my opinion multiple workstations require a proper DB server.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express is a microsoft product and thereby directly supported by Visual Studio. You can never get it wrong when using microsofts products together.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0**. It acts just like SQL server and allows you to have the database on the same work station.

Check it out [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with one of the Microsoft Databases as support for connectivity comes pretty easily through the .NET framework (note that MS have deprecated their own Oracle .NET Data Provider).  Yes you can get a third-party library but if you go with a MS database then it's built into the framework and you can avoid a dependency on an external librray.

So, SQL Server Express Edition would be my preferred choice, but beware that there are size restrictions on the amount of data you can put into a database (4GB if I remember correctly) - normally enough for small applications but something to be mindful of.